# Sometimes if I attach the camera to an animation path lost its perspective view

Tags: animation, camera, path

I did a turntable animation and attached the camera to an animation path (circle) but when I see thru the camera view it looks like an ortho view rather than a perspective view. What can I do to solve this? In the perspective view I can see the accentuated perspective but not in the camera view.

Comment: Have you checked in your camera settings if it's set to "Orthographic"?

Comment: I had but nothing change. The camera is still like an ortho camera without perspective. Maybe is a bug when is attached to a curve. I was using it that way to make a turn table animation